# I need to get rid of the parentheses around a number inside of a <span>

Tags: javascript, slice, parentheses

I found a way to do it with jQuery but I need pure javascript I can put in `<script>` tags.

```
<span class="slicethis">(10)</span>

$('span.slicethis').text(function (_,txt) {
    return txt.slice(1, -1);});
```

The jQuery jsfiddle is: http://jsfiddle.net/d72ML/1062/

Can someone help me out?

Comment: You need to give more details. If your code could look like this: http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/u13ym3op/ we would need to loop

Answer (score 2):

Just replace `jquery` with `querySelector` and set `textContent` instead of `text`

```
var el = document.querySelector('span.slicethis');
el.textContent = el.textContent.slice(1, -1);
```

**Demo**

```js
var el = document.querySelector('span.slicethis');
el.textContent = el.textContent.slice(1, -1);
```

```html
<span class='slicethis'>(10)</span>
```

**Edit**

`$('span.slicethis')` **iterate over all the items that match this selector**, so if there are going to be multiple such elements, then you need to iterate them using `querySelectorAll`

```
[ ...document.querySelectorAll('span.slicethis') ].forEach( function(el){
    el.textContent = el.textContent.slice(1, -1);  
});
```

```js
[ ...document.querySelectorAll('span.slicethis') ].forEach( function(el){
    el.textContent = el.textContent.slice(1, -1);  
});
```

```html
<span class='slicethis'>(1)</span>
<span class='slicethis'>(10)</span>
<span class='slicethis'>(100)</span>
```

Comment: @mplungjan You are right. I have updated the answer.

Comment: If you're going to show a solution like this, then please explain what your answer does, and how it works. At the very least explain what the `...` (spread) operator does, and why you're using it.

Answer (score 1):

To remove parenthesis, you can use some regex to replace it `replace(/\)|\(/g, "")` inorder to remove multiple parenthesis instead of `.slice` and use `innerHTML` to set/get the html content

```js
var el = document.getElementsByClassName("slicethis")[0];
el.innerHTML = el.innerHTML.replace(/\)|\(/g, "");
```

```html
<span class="slicethis">(10)</span>
```

Comment: querySelectorAll is more compatible and you likely need to loop to get all spans involved

Comment: @mplungjan agreed. But that depends on the use case of OP. I was just highlighting the way to do it.

Answer (score -1):

That's overkill. No JQuery needed for simple string operation. The `String.substr(start, numChars)` method does the trick.

```js
console.log(document.querySelector(".slicethis").textContent.substr(1,2));
```

```html
<span class="slicethis">(10)</span>
```

Comment: Not the down-voter, but if you're going to post a jQuery-alternative (which is exactly what the OP wanted, obviously) bear in mind that there are features of that jQuery approach you haven't replicated; which is the difference between `document.querySelector()` and `document.querySelectorAll()`.

Comment: Not to mention if the number is smaller or larger than 2 digits

Comment: @DavidThomas I am aware of the difference, but the OP has not stated that he has multiple elements to work on. In fact, he has stated the opposite, which is why `.querySelector()` was shown.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/u13ym3op/ handles multiple spans with different content